# resizing SVG in dc.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to resize the SVGs in [dc.js](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/). 
In the NASDAQ example in the main page itself. When I change the width/height, it cuts of the svg instead of resizing it. For example, changing width and height to half .. it cuts the svg into half and only shows half of it. I know I am doing something really silly here.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did. In my HTML page I had the following line:

```
<div id="resize"></div>
```

In my js page, I setup a bar chart graph called "barChart." I had the following sequence:

```
var width = document.getElementById("resize").offsetWidth;

barChart = dc.barChart("#barChart");

barChart.width(width)
  .height(350)
  .margins({top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 40})
  .dimension(rooms)
  .group(kWOccupiedData)
  .elasticY(true)
  .gap(1)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0, 5]))
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .yAxisLabel("kWh")
  .xAxisLabel("Room")
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .transitionDuration(700);

window.onresize = function(event) {
  var newWidth = document.getElementById("resize").offsetWidth;

  barChart.width(newWidth / 2)
    .transitionDuration(0);

  dc.renderAll();

  barChart.transitionDuration(750);
};
```

Lastly, in my CSS stylesheet I put:

```
.resize {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

#barChart {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now when you resize your window, the chart should resize as well.

Comment: Seems complicated and slow compared to using a viewBox which is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use viewBox attribute.

> The viewBox attribute allows to specify that a given set of graphics
>   stretch to fit a particular container element.
>   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Here is example - http://jsfiddle.net/LPWhE/ 
If you change container's width and height in css you resize svg.

```
svg.attr({
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%",
    "viewBox": "0 0 250 250"
})
```